# Display php nested array results continuously in two column table

Tags: php, arrays, nested, html-table

I have a nested array grouping three other arrays: $online, $busy and $offline, in order to display results in this exactly order.

```
$conteudo = array($online, $ocupado, $offline);
```

The desired result would be a table in two columns to display results in continuous flow like this:

```
online1 | online2
online3 | busy1
busy2   | offline1
offline2| offline3
offline4|
```

I've been trying lots of `foreach` loops and playing around changing the html tags, but the closest I can arrive of the desired result is this:

```
<table width='100%' cellpadding='5' border="1">
<?php
$i = 1; //contador de colunas
$max_colunas = 2; // numero de colunas
foreach ($conteudo as $row) {
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($row as $col) {
        foreach ($col as $cell) {
            if ($i == 1) {
                echo "<td>" . $cell . "</td>";
            } elseif ($i == $max_colunas){
                echo "<td>" . $cell . "</td></tr>";
                $i = 0;
            } else {
                echo "<td>" . $cell . "</td>";
            }
            $i++;
        }
    }   
    echo "</tr>"; 
}
```

This code will output a table like this:

```
 onine1  | online2 |online3
 busy1   | busy2   |
 offline1|offline2 |offline3|offline4
```

I can't find out why it ignores completely `$max_colunas`, seems like it prints all the elements inside the array in row.

If I remove lines:

```
 echo "<tr>";
 echo "</tr>";
```

from beginning and end of `foreach` it will output all in a row like this:

```
onine1  | online2 |online3 | busy1 | busy2 |offline1|offline2 |offline3|offline4
```

Any suggestions to get the desired output format will be so appreciated.

---

Edited on 17/01:

This is how I'm getting the arrays from:

```
//group people
$online = array(); //group online
$ocupado = array(); //group ocupado
$offline = array(); //group offline

//select people to group
$atendentes = mysql_query("SELECT nome FROM atendentes ORDER BY nome") or die(mysql_error());
$atendentedb = array();

//put selected people in array
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($atendentes)) {
    $atendentedb[] = array('nome' => $row["nome"], 'online' => false);
}


//take people online now and check in selected people
$names = modWhosonlineCustom::getOnlineUserNames();

foreach ($names as $name):
    //foreach ($atendentedb as $atendente):
    for($i = 0; $i < count($atendentedb); $i++):
        $att = strtolower($name->username);

        if ($atendentedb[$i]['nome'] == $att):          
            $atendentedb[$i]['online'] = true;
            break;
        endif;

   endfor;
endforeach;

//check each selected people
foreach ($atendentedb as $atendente) :
    //save temporary data
    $online_ = $atendente['online'];
    $nome_   = $atendente['nome'];  

    //if selected people online
    if ($online_) :
        //take status to show
        $status = mysql_query("SELECT status FROM atendentes WHERE nome = '$nome_' LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($status)):
            $statusdb = $row["status"];
        endwhile;

        //verify and save deppending on status
        switch ($statusdb):

            //if online
            case "disponivel":
                $descricao = mysql_query("SELECT hp_online FROM atendentes WHERE nome = '$nome_' LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($descricao)):
                $online[] = array('info'=>$row['hp_online']);
                endwhile;
                break;

        //if busy
            case "ocupado":
                $descricao = mysql_query("SELECT hp_busy FROM atendentes WHERE nome = '$nome_'  LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($descricao)):
                    $ocupado[] = array('info'=>$row['hp_busy']);
                endwhile;
                break;
        endswitch;

    //if offline
    else:
        $descricao = mysql_query("SELECT hp_offline, horario FROM atendentes WHERE nome = '$nome_' LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($descricao)):
           $offline[] = array('info'=>$row['hp_offline'], 'horario'=>$row['horario']);
        endwhile;

    endif;
endforeach;
```

**EDITED**

So after following help instructions from DaveRandom I got to this code, which is really a drop away from the right format, except for the "mysterious" behaviour with results coming from array `$offline`, that are displaying all in "block" (all cells in a row, or all cells in a column) while the other arrays are displaying perfectly(??).

```
   //group people
   $online = $ocupado = $offline = array();

   //select people to group
   $query = "SELECT nome, status, hp_online, hp_busy, hp_offline, horario
      FROM atendentes
      ORDER BY nome";
  $atendentes = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
  $atendentedb = array();

  // put selected people in array
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($atendentes)) {
  $atendentedb[strtolower($row['nome'])] = array_merge($row, array('online' => FALSE));
  }

  //take people online now and check in selected people
  $names = modWhosonlineCustom::getOnlineUserNames();
  foreach ($names as $name) {
  $uname = strtolower($name->username);
  if (isset($atendentedb[$uname])) $atendentedb[$uname]['online'] = TRUE;
  }

  //check each selected people
  foreach ($atendentedb as $name => $atendente) {

  //if selected people online
  if ($atendente['online']) {

 //verify and save deppending on status
 switch ($atendente['status']) {

  //if online
  case 'disponivel':
    $atendentedb[$name]['info'] = $online[] = $atendente['hp_online'];
    break;

  //if busy
  case 'ocupado':
    $atendentedb[$name]['info'] = $ocupado[] = $atendente['hp_busy'];
    break;

  }

  //if offline
  } else {

  $atendentedb[$name]['info'] = $offline[] = $atendente['hp_offline'];
$atendentedb[$name]['info'] = $offline[] = $atendente['horario'];

  }

}

  //*******Display Results
  $conteudo = array_merge($online, $ocupado, $offline);
  $max_colunas = 2; // numero de colunas

  // Start the table
  echo '<table width="100%" cellpadding="5" border="1">'."\n";

  // Loop all the objects
  for ($i = 0, $j = 0; isset($conteudo[$i]); $i++) {
  if ($j == 0) {
  // Output the beginning of a row
  echo "  <tr>\n";
  }
  // Always output a data cell
  echo "    <td>$conteudo[$i]</td>\n";
  if (++$j >= $max_colunas) {
  // Output the end of a row and reset the cell counter
  echo "  </tr>\n";
  $j = 0;
  }
  }

  if ($j) {
  // We may end up with an incomplete row at the end, so pad it with empty cells
  // and close the row
  while ($j++ < $max_colunas) {
 echo "    <td></td>\n";
 }
 echo "  </tr>\n";
 }

 // Close the table
 echo "</table>";
```

Comment: initialize $i in front of  foreach ($col as $cell)

Comment: What's the format of the arrays?  you're nesting too deep for an array of 1-dimensional arrays.

Comment: Greg Bair I'm not sure what you mean to say with "format" or the arrays, but I suspect my problem is really something related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that the first thing to do here is to "flatten" the array - having the multiple dimensions makes this a lot more complicated than it needs to be. So rather than creating `$conteudo` like this:

```
$conteudo = array($online, $ocupado, $offline);
```

...do this instead:

```
$conteudo = array_merge($online, $ocupado, $offline);
```

Then you can do this:

```
$max_colunas = 2; // numero de colunas

// Start the table
echo '<table width="100%" cellpadding="5" border="1">'."\n";

// Loop all the objects
for ($i = 0, $j = 0; isset($conteudo[$i]); $i++) {
  if ($j == 0) {
    // Output the beginning of a row
    echo "  <tr>\n";
  }
  // Always output a data cell
  echo "    <td>$conteudo[$i]</td>\n";
  if (++$j >= $max_colunas) {
    // Output the end of a row and reset the cell counter
    echo "  </tr>\n";
    $j = 0;
  }
}

if ($j) {
  // We may end up with an incomplete row at the end, so pad it with empty cells
  // and close the row
  while ($j++ < $max_colunas) {
    echo "    <td></td>\n";
  }
  echo "  </tr>\n";
}

// Close the table
echo "</table>";
```

[See it working](http://codepad.org/kijorosg)

**EDIT**

Try this code for generating your arrays. Note that the structure of your output arrays has been altered to fit my code sample above - if you use this data anywhere else in you script,  you will need to modify that code as well. I have modified this so that there is only one database query, which would seem to be all that is required. I have also modified it so that the `$atendentedb` holds all the user data, including the `status` and `info` keys, and all rows contain a `horario` key.

Because of the fact that your input arrays originally contained more data than the ones created by this code will, the code may need further modification - but try this out and see how you get on.

```
//group people
$online = $ocupado = $offline = array();

//select people to group
$query = "SELECT nome, status, hp_online, hp_busy, hp_offline, horario
          FROM atendentes
          ORDER BY nome";
$atendentes = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$atendentedb = array();

// put selected people in array
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($atendentes)) {
  $atendentedb[strtolower($row['nome'])] = array_merge($row, array('online' => FALSE));
}

//take people online now and check in selected people
$names = modWhosonlineCustom::getOnlineUserNames();
foreach ($names as $name) {
  $uname = strtolower($name->username);
  if (isset($atendentedb[$uname])) $atendentedb[$uname]['online'] = TRUE;
}

//check each selected people
foreach ($atendentedb as $name => $atendente) {

  //if selected people online
  if ($atendente['online']) {

    //verify and save deppending on status
    switch ($atendente['status']) {

      //if online
      case 'disponivel':
        $atendentedb[$name]['info'] = $online[] = $atendente['hp_online'];
        break;

      //if busy
      case 'ocupado':
        $atendentedb[$name]['info'] = $ocupado[] = $atendente['hp_busy'];
        break;

    }

  //if offline
  } else {

    $atendentedb[$name]['info'] = $offline[] = $atendente['hp_offline'].' '.$atendente['horario'];

  }

}
```

Comment: DaveRandom Thanks really a lot for this code, it works like a charm in your example but I must have still something wrong with my arrays $online, $ocupado, $offline since when I apply your example in my code I get this:

array | array

Comment: I just added how I'm getting the arrays for you to have an idea if you can give me any other suggestions!

Comment: I just tryed your code inside the original loops 'foreach ($col as $cell) {}' and I got the results in the right order but with the strings completly splitout by the isset. Removing isset is not working, do you know how to fix it?

Comment: WOW thanks really a lot this seems far more legible and organized!:D I tryed it just adding the following: '$atendentedb[$name]['info'] = $offline[] = $atendente['horario'];' after case offline to display together with the results of hp_offline. I'm missing one drop to get it completly done, when I output it all results for people "offline" displays in "block" (which result in its cell, but it builds all in a row or all in a column). Just for "offline" people (???) online and busy displays perfectly. Seems that this array got something diferent but I just can't see what.

Comment: How do you want to display the value of `horario`? What you are doing is creating two cells for each offline entry, which is not what you want - how do you want it to display (presumably with the data from `hp_offline` and `horario` in the same cell)?

Comment: Yes! exactly, those results contain html code, one hp_offline contains the start tags and horario contains the end tags so they need to display together in the same cell that's why it's messing up! Do you know how can I do it?

Comment: Well you just need to combine the two bits of data into a single string. So you could (for example) change the `$atendentedb[$name]['info'] = $offline[] = $atendente['hp_offline'];` in my code to `$atendentedb[$name]['info'] = $offline[] = $atendente['hp_offline'].' '.$atendente['horario'];` - it's just a single string concatenation. I suspect you are over-complicating it in your head because you have been looking at it for too long ;-)

Comment: I have edited the code in my answer because it didn't come out very well in the comment.

Comment: I think so!! Thanks sooooooooooooo much, this definitely solved the problem and now works like a charm!!! <:D

Answer (score 0):

I think you should update counter inside
`foreach ($col as $cell) { }` so it will count elements of the inner arrays and also move decalration of `<tr>` there.
`if (!is_int($i/2)) { print '<tr><td>' }`

Comment: it may work so: `foreach ($conteudo as $row) {
    foreach ($row as $col) {
        foreach ($col as $cell){
            if ($i==1){
                echo "<tr><td>".$cell."</td>";
  $i++;
            } elseif ($i==$max_colunas) {
                echo "<td>".$cell."</td></tr>";
                $i=1;
  }
        }
    }   
}`

Comment: Sergiy T sorry I deleted the first comment since I've found why it didn't work. With your first suggestion I've got a interesting table, results are outputting but I really can't see the logic for the order of the html output. I tryied your code but output now is nothing :/

Comment: @Adry Sorry, missed else part so it'll be `if($i==1) {  }  elseif($i==$max_colunas) {  }  else { echo "<td>".$cell."</td>"; $i++; }`